# VBA code to move unique values from one Excel document to another Excel document with several sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm a total noob and basically don't know any VBA but I would be grateful if someone could help me out!
I try to be as clear as possible.

Every month I download an Excel file from Dynamics 365  (with a generic name such as **(484trijtsfgnsrt9rjtritisrgjrkji37849.xlx)** ) that contains 11 columns and maybe 500-1000 rows, with information about our customers. It looks something like this:

[Simplified version of raw Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ru6i.png)

Every month, I need to do the following:

1. I insert an empty row between each unique customer. I sort by customer ID (in this case B1:B9) using the following script :

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Wrng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleID = "Test"
Set Wrng = Application.Selection
Set Wrng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleID, Wrng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = Wrng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If Wrng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Wrng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        Wrng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This gives me a list that looks something like this:

[Raw Excel file after blank rows have been inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IdZe.png)

2. Here is the tricky part; I need to copy each unique customer from the raw Excel file and paste it into *separate* sheets in another Excel file called **[month.xlx]** (in August the file would be called **August.xlx** , in September I will call it **September.xlx**) where `total number of unique customers = total number of sheets.`

I need to paste each customer into a new sheet between rows 9 - 18 in a template in the file **month.xlx** e.g this month; "August.xlx". It will look something like this:

[Unique customers transferd to new Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFHL5.png)

There are some caveats:

A) Every month, the number of customers change. One month there can be 487 customers, the next month maybe 876 customers etc.

B) A customer that is shown in August e.g. "Adam", might not be shown next month, September.

C) Customers makes irregular purchases. If "Adam" made 3 purchases in the August report, he might make 1 purchase next month. While "Sara J." for example, made 1 purchase in the August file, could make 6 purchases in September etc.

D) The raw Excel file generated by Dynamics 365 has a unique random name every month.

I would be very grateful if anyone has a solutions, since this process takes me many hours to do manually every month.

Thank you and kind regards,

QuarterlyReport

Comment: some stuff to google to get you started: Excel VBA for loop, Excel VBA sheets.add, Excel VBA unique value

Comment: Thanks Alex! I also thought about merging the two files into one. I guess it will be easier to transfer from one sheet to another, instead of one documen to another document.